# How can I turn a ParamArray with ranges, individual cells and/or direct inputs to an Array?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build a UDF that will accept a ParamArray that will accept one cell, a range of cells, and/or a direct value. I need to then loop through the ParamArray to get all the values passed, but when I try to ReDim an array, it gets stuck and the loop ends. Am I just doing this completely wrong because this just seems like too much work.

```
Function myudf(first As Variant, ParamArray args() As Variant)
    Dim i, j As Long
    Dim argsarray() As Variant
    ReDim argsarray(0, 0)

    For i = 0 To UBound(args)
        If Not IsObject(args(i)) Then
            ReDim Preserve argsarray(0 To UBound(argsarray) + 1)
            argsarray(i) = args(i) ' Handle explicitly passed arguments, e.g. "1,goonie,etc")

        ElseIf IsArray(args(i).Value2) Then
            For j = 1 To UBound(args(i).Value2)
                ReDim Preserve argsarray(0 To UBound(argsarray) + 1)
                argsarray(UBound(argsarray) + 1) = args(j).Value2 ' Handle a range of cells, e.g. A1:A3
            Next j
        Else
            ReDim Preserve argsarray(0 To UBound(argsarray) + 1)
            argsarray(i) = args(i).Value2 ' Handle individual cells, e.g. A1)
        End If
    Next i

    myudf = Join(argsarray, ",")

End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two-dimmentsion array `ReDim argsarray(0, 0)`.

As follow up from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w8k3cys2.aspx):

> If you use `Preserve`, you can resize *only the last dimension* of the
>   array. For every other dimension, you must specify the bound of the
>   existing array.

So, this doesn't work `ReDim Preserve argsarray(0 To UBound(argsarray) + 1)`, but this one works `ReDim Preserve argsarray(0, 0 To UBound(argsarray) + 1)`.

Btw, `Preserve` is very expensive operation. I suggets you to review your code and use single `ReDim argsarray` after counting all cells

Try this one instead:

```
Function myudf(first As Variant, ParamArray args() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, cnt As Long
    Dim argsarray() As Variant

    Dim c, rng

    For Each rng In args
        If IsObject(rng) Then
            cnt = cnt + rng.Cells.Count
        ElseIf IsArray(rng) Then
            cnt = cnt + UBound(rng)
        Else
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next

    ReDim argsarray(1 To cnt)

    i = 1
    For Each rng In args
        If IsObject(rng) Or IsArray(rng) Then
            For Each c In rng
                argsarray(i) = c
                i = i + 1
            Next
        Else
            argsarray(i) = rng
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    myudf = Join(argsarray, ",")
End Function
```

If the purpose of UDF is only to join values, you can use this one as well:

```
Function myudf2(first As Variant, ParamArray args() As Variant)       
    Dim c, rng

    For Each rng In args
        If IsObject(rng) Or IsArray(rng) Then
            For Each c In rng
                myudf2 = myudf2 & c & ","
            Next
        Else
            myudf2 = myudf2 & rng & ","
        End If
    Next

    myudf2 = Left(myudf2, Len(myudf2) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: ah, yes, I screwed up...it s/b a 1-dimensional array. Your code handles only ranges, correct?

Comment: yeah, it supposed that `args()` contains ranges, but you can easily modify it

Comment: I need the udf to handle a range and/or a value and/or a single cell reference

Comment: Try my updated function. It handles `range`/`cell reference`/`value`/`array of values`. You can call it like `=myudf(E3,F3,H3:I3)` or `=myudf(E3,F3,"a",H3:I3)` or `=myudf(E3,F3,{"a","b"},H3:I3)` and so on

Comment: @simoco +1 nice answer but just a few comments: correct me if i am wrong but the array handling bit (`cnt = cnt + UBound(rng)`) will only work with 1-d arrays and will also not do as intented if the array is not base 1? Also, enumerating the passed in range can be pretty slow for large numbers of cells, loading it into a temp array first is generally a lot faster. Have a look at the pattern I use in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382416/in-excel-2010-how-could-i-remove-duplicates-and-concatenate-values-within-a-cel/22417488#22417488.

Comment: thanks, 1) in original question OP says `ParamArray that will accept one cell, a range of cells, and/or a direct value`, so I didn't complicate the code for the general case (for 2-d array and so on). 2) of course, working with array is faster than loop through range, but my intension was not to optimise the code, but show another way of doing it without `Preserve`

Comment: @simico good point - I always go off on tangents - if the question was to handle x then ignore my ramblings about y :-)